# Find the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{n}j$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{n}j$

for all $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$.

How do I find/evaluate this sum?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

- add first and last term to get $n+1$
- next pair (next to last and second) gives the same result
- see [Gauss Trick](http://nzmaths.co.nz/gauss-trick-staff-seminar)

Comment: I don't get your first hint, could you elaborate?

Comment: @jukka.aalto first term in your sum and last term added together are $n+1$. Next pair is $2 + (n-1) = n+1$. etc

Answer (score 3):

Consider:
$$S = \sum_{j=0}^n x^j = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x - 1}$$
$$\frac {d}{dx}S = \sum_{j=0}^njx^{j-1} = \frac{nx^{n+1} - (n+1)x^n + 1}{(x-1)^2}$$

If we take the limit as $x \to 1$, the left hand side becomes $\sum_{j=0}^n j$, and we can evaluate the RHS to find a function of $n$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{nx^{n+1} - (n+1)x^n + 1}{(x-1)^2} = \lim_{x\to1}\frac{n(n+1)x^n - (n+1)nx^{n-1}}{2(x-1)}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to1}\frac{n(n+1)x^n - (n+1)nx^{n-1}}{2(x-1)} = \lim_{x\to1}x^{n-1}\frac{(n+1)n}{2} = \frac{(n+1)n}{2}$$

Comment: This is an obscure way to derive a basic result.

Comment: @SimonS It was more of a sarcastic answer. In fact I'm surprised no one has flagged this question as a duplicate yet

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof without words that should help, just generalize from there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **high school** argument which I love more! :)

Assume $n$ is an odd positive integer then

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n j  = 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 2) + (n - 1) + n  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \left( {0 + n} \right) + \left( {1 + \left( {n - 1} \right)} \right) + \left( {2 + \left( {n - 2} \right)} \right) + ...  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \underbrace {n + n + n + ...}_{{{n + 1} \over 2}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \left( {{{n + 1} \over 2}} \right)n = {{n(n + 1)} \over 2} \cr} $$

you can argue **most** similarly when $n$ is an even number! I will leave this case as an exercise for you. :)